# Data manipulation in D3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

I have the following data:

```
var data = [
  {Name:"A", Var:"15", Temp:"20",Lo:"T"},
  {Name:"B", Var:"45", Temp:"40",Lo:"F"},
  {Name:"B", Var:"63", Temp:"340",Lo:"T"},
  {Name:"A", Var:"415", Temp:"450",Lo:"F"},
  {Name:"B", Var:"405", Temp:"940",Lo:"F"},
  {Name:"B", Var:"415", Temp:"410",Lo:"T"},
  {Name:"A", Var:"24", Temp:"51",Lo:"T"},
  {Name:"C", Var:"43", Temp:"40",Lo:"T"},
  {Name:"A", Var:"41", Temp:"40",Lo:"F"}
]
```

I filter the data to get

```
dataFiltered = [
  {Name:"A", Var:"15", Temp:"20",Lo:"T"},
  {Name:"A", Var:"415", Temp:"450",Lo:"F"},
  {Name:"A", Var:"24", Temp:"51",Lo:"T"},
  {Name:"A", Var:"41", Temp:"40",Lo:"F"}
]
```

But I want to have a new array of objects like:

```
dataNew = [
  {Vt:"35", Tv:"5"},
  {Vt:"865", Tv:"35"},
  {Vt:"75", Tv:"27"},
  {Vt:"80", Tv:"-1"}
]
```

Finally I want to use `dataNew` to present the aggregated data for `Vt (35+865+75+80)` and `Tv (5+35+27-1)` on a pie chart.

> Note `Vt = Var + Temp` and `Tv = Temp - Var` from `dataFiltered`.

I really do not know what to do after filtering the data and in particular how to get `dataNew`.

I leave the code for the filtering part here as well.

```
var filteredData = data.filter(function(d) {
    return d.Name == "A";
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map that filtered data to desired format using `map` and than you can use `reduce` to get total of `Tv` and `Vt` values

```js
let dataFiltered = [{Name:"A", Var:"15", Temp:"20",Lo:"T"},{Name:"A", Var:"415", Temp:"450",Lo:"F"},{Name:"A", Var:"24", Temp:"51",Lo:"T"},{Name:"A", Var:"41", Temp:"40",Lo:"F"},]
        
let newData = dataFiltered.map(({Var, Temp}) => {
  let Vt = Number(Var) + Number(Temp)
  let Tv = Temp - Var
  return {Vt,Tv}  
})

console.log(newData)

let aggregateData = newData.reduce((op,{Tv,Vt})=>{
  op['Tv'] = op['Tv'] || 0
  op['Vt'] = op['Vt'] || 0
  op['Tv'] +=Tv
  op['Vt'] +=Vt
  return op
},{})

console.log(aggregateData)
```

Comment: Do I need to redefine dataFiltered again the way you did or is it enough to start with original data and then do filtering and use dataFiltered as given by data.filter() .

Comment: @Mathnewbie no it's fine to start with original data and then filter, i just given example of things where you're facing problem, you can incorporate these thing in your code where

Comment: Thanks I did incorporate your solution and it works well. However, I still seem to struggle with the second part of the question to do a pie chart using aggregateDate. It seems pie chart requires a different data structure. Am I correct or  can we still do pie chart using aggregateData?

Comment: Sorry! I have been trying to modify your code to get averages over different values of Tv and Vt but I have not been successful. So now we only some different values of Tv and Vt but I want their average. Could please help with that? I couldnt figure it our using the other code provided either.

Comment: @Mathnewbie you can calculate average just by dividing the total / filteredData.length,

Comment: Thanks but where do you do that. I tried return op/newData.lenght I received NaN. Same with aggregateData/newData.lenght. Sorry a bit new with JS!

Comment: You should do it after aggregateData, It's should be length not lenght, second thing you should do is aggregateData.Tv/newData.length to get average of Tv is same way you can count for Vt,

Comment: Any idea on the pie chart bit for example for aggregateData=["Vt":43,"Tv":57], I do not seem to find a tutorial. The examples are either data like [43,57] or ["V":43,"V":57] (having same key. I want to show on my part chart that Vt=43 and Tv=57 anod not just their numerical values

Comment: d3.js Yes there are heaps but they seem to be working with a different data structure.

Comment: @Mathnewbie you need to have data structures in required form of library, you can't just do with any random data structure

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the output you need in one iteration over the original data using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to generate an `object` with the new array of data and the accumulated values for `Vt` and `Tv`, example:

```js
var data = [
  {Name:"A", Var:"15", Temp:"20", Lo:"T"},
  {Name:"B", Var:"45", Temp:"40", Lo:"F"},
  {Name:"B", Var:"63", Temp:"340", Lo:"T"},
  {Name:"A", Var:"415", Temp:"450", Lo:"F"},
  {Name:"B", Var:"405", Temp:"940", Lo:"F"},
  {Name:"B", Var:"415", Temp:"410", Lo:"T"},
  {Name:"A", Var:"24", Temp:"51", Lo:"T"},
  {Name:"C", Var:"43", Temp:"40", Lo:"T"},
  {Name:"A", Var:"41", Temp:"40", Lo:"F"}
];

function reduceData(data, type)
{
    return data.reduce((acc, {Name, Var, Temp}) =>
    {
        if (Name !== type)
            return acc;

        let Vt = (+Var) + (+Temp), Tv = Temp - Var;
        let len = acc.newData.push({Vt, Tv});
        acc.acc_vt += Vt;
        acc.acc_tv += Tv;
        acc.avg_tv = (acc.avg_tv * (len-1) + Tv) / len;
        acc.avg_vt = (acc.avg_vt * (len-1) + Vt) / len;
        return acc;

    }, {newData: [], acc_vt: 0, acc_tv: 0, avg_vt: 0, avg_tv: 0})
}

console.log(reduceData(data, "A"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: WoW! This is a very efficient way of doing it. Is there also an efficient way of doing averaging over different values of vt and tv. Currently, I see you do the aggregation (summation) using acc.acc_vt and acc.acc_tv. Is there a way to do averaging without dividing the aggregated data by the length (acc.acc_tv/length). Something like a mean function.

Comment: @Mathnewbie I have updated to iteratively calculate the average also, but i'm not really sure if you where looking for that.

Comment: Thanks! It works well. I thought there was a way do it non-iteratively but this works well so I might use this. Is there any idea about the second part of the question and how to get a pie chart using  acc_vt(or avg_vt) and acc_tv( or avg_tv).

Comment: Mmm, you can get the average if you do, for example, `let avg_vt = acc_vt / newData.length` from the returned object of `reduce()`, speaking about the first version of the implementation. I'm not familiarized with `D3` library, but for sure, there should be any tutorial on how to make a pie chart.